# VBA - representing hierarchical data in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, hierarchy

I am fairly new to VBA in Excel and was hoping for some guidance on this problem. I am given hierarchical data from a database to perform a report, and the user would like to format the information such that an entry's children lie directly below it (a parent can have multiple children, child has only one parent). This could perhaps be done by indenting the Notes tab of the data by a few spaces. I was wondering how to first perform the reordering of the data by hierarchy, and then visually showing an indentation by adding, say, 5 spaces to the beginning of the Notes tab.
For sample data:

```
ID  Parent ID   Notes
0   NULL        This is number 0.
1   0           This is number 1.
2   0           This is number 2.
3   1           This is number 3.
4   3           This is number 4.
5   0           This is number 5.
```

I would then like the data to be presented as such:

```
ID  Parent ID   Notes
0   NULL        This is number 0.
1   0           -----This is number 1.
3   0           -----This is number 3.
4   1           ----------This is number 4.
2   3           -----This is number 2.
5   0           -----This is number 5.
```

Thank you so much! Your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Your logic defeats me. There is an `insertindent` method. Perhaps you can sort the data, but as I say ...

Comment: Why not use a pivot table for this? Especially if you are 'new' to VBA. Accomplishing this task with VBA (without prior VBA knowledge) would take you a while, and it would likely be a very fragile solution at best.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @BrandonBarney! Would the ability to place an ID's children dynamically below it as shown above be available using a PivotTable?

Comment: Pivot tables automatically allow grouping by `Category` of sorts. So given a parent `X` all the children will be shown below it if their `Parent` property is X. You may have issues though if you need a `Parent` record because a `Parent` record cant have a parent, and thus wont appear within the pivot table as a category. Basically, try playing and learning Pivot Tables. It shouldnt be too difficult to figure out if you do use a pivot table.